# SharePoint 2010 Two search boxes on the master page

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

I would like to have two search boxes on my master page.
One that would search for content and the other one that would search for people.

I see the code in the master page that searches for content:

How would i do to add another box that searches for people?

if you know or have info on how to achieve this I would appreciate it.
thank you much
W

Comment: Check out the identical question on SharePoint Stack Exchange, [How to configure two search boxes - one for people and one for content?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/how-to-configure-two-search-boxes-one-for-people-and-one-for-content). Both questions were asked within two minutes of each other but by two different user IDs. Same person perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something simple which is to put an HTML text box directly in your master page. It may not be as elegant as writing a customer user control that reads the location of the Search site, but if the URL to your search results page is static then something like this might work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SearchPeople()
{           
    var termArr = document.getElementById("SearchTextBoxPeople").value.split(" ");
    var retStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < termArr.length; i++) {
        retStr += termArr[i] + "* ";
    }
    document.location.href = "/Search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=" + retStr;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="SearchTextBoxPeople" />
<a href="#" onclick="SearchPeople();">Search People</a>
```

One additional benefit of this is that you can control the input to include wildcards (which are horrible out-of-the-box for people searches).  The JavaScript is simply including * in the search which allows wildcard searches.  So a search for `jo sm` will actually send `jo* sm*` to the search page which will then match on John Smith.